# MVC app deployment; System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Could not find stored procedure 'ELMAH_GetErrorsXml'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah

I have deployed my MVC app but the error handling does not work.
I use a SQLite database and when I try to navigate to the error messages in Elmah i get this exception;

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Could not find stored procedure 'ELMAH_GetErrorsXml'.

Of course I need to deploy the SQLite database, defined in my web.config as;

add name="ELMAH.SQLite" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|errors.s3db" />

I am thinking that I did not deploy a SQLite database when I deployed my application. Yet I cannot locate the errors.s3db on my local file system, so I am not sure how I set one up on my live environment.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You'll need to run the SQL script to create the ELMAH objects. It can be found in the 'db' folder of the download ( http://code.google.com/p/elmah/downloads/list )

Comment: Yes, I found out I was using the SQL database and the SQLite was a red herring. I better remove that.