# Where does ELMAH save its data?

Tags: c#, .net, elmah

I just installed ELMAH.MVC (more info [here](http://nuget.org/packages/Elmah.MVC)) and was wondering where its data is saved. I read that you can choose to set up database for storage but seems that the default install uses "in memory"? How does it work? If I recycle the app pool or IIS website do I loose all the data? Thanks!

Comment: [This](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) is a more helpful link for more information.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/elmah/

Comment: You set most options in web.config/app.config, if you check the example one, you'll see (reasonable) instructions how to set various types of storage up.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, by default it uses memory storage. When your application pool is restarted, you loose elmah data. If I remember well, old versions of elmah used App_Data folder for storing xml files...If you want to use database to store logs, just specify connection string in your elmah config section:

```
<elmah>
...
<errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="ElmahConnectionString"/> 

...
</elmah>
```

You should have ElmahConnectionString in your connectionStrings section, something like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ElmahConnectionString "
         connectionString="Initial Catalog=my_database;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
...
</connectionStrings>
```

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/downloads/detail?name=ELMAH-1.2-sp2-sample-web.config) you can find example web.config file.

Comment: I'm getting "Could not find stored procedure 'ELMAH_GetErrorsXml'."! Already installed http://nuget.org/packages/elmah.sqlserver but still same problem. Remember I'm using Elmah.MVC on top of Elmah (not sure if it makes a difference). Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Got it! response http://stackoverflow.com/a/5380167/1133338 . I had to manually run the sql script to create the table. So I was wondering what nuget.org/packages/elmah.sqlserver did (other than adding an empty connection string to my web.config?

Comment: It probably just added errorLog entry to the elmah config...it cannot manipulate your database because it "doesn't know" how to connect to it.

Answer (score 4):

Read in "Examining the ErrorLog Class" topic, and you will find your answer

[Using HTTP Modules and Handlers to Create Pluggable ASP.NET Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479332.aspx)